# define vector by magnitude in matlab

Tags: vectors, matlab

I am working with MATLAB and I should draw some vectors which I have their lengths and angles. Does anyone know how it is possible?

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/plotv.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
R = [1,2,3,4,5]; % radii
Theta = [pi/3, 2*pi/3, pi, 4*pi/3, 5*pi/3]; % angles
X = R .* cos(Theta);
Y = R .* sin(Theta);
compass(X,Y)
```

[image]